# sqoop import unable to locate sqoop-1.4.6.jar

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm using sqoop for importing data from mysql table to be used with hadoop.
While importing it is showing error.

**Hadoop Version: 2.5.0**
**Sqoop Version: 1.4.6**

**Command Used for import**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/<dbname> --username root --password pass@123 --table <tablename> -m 1
```

**Error Shown**

```
15/05/27 23:13:59 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6.jar
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**1. Create a directory in HDFS:**

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /usr/lib/sqoop
```

**2. Copy sqoop jar into HDFS:**

```
hdfs dfs -put /usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/
```

**3. Check whether the file exists in HDFS:**

```
hdfs dfs -ls /usr/lib/sqoop
```

**4. Import using sqoop:**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/<dbname> --username root --password pass@123 --table <tablename> -m 1
```